# Exception getting Resource from Jedis pool when connecting via Redis Sentinel nodes

Tags: spring-boot, redis, redis-sentinel, redis-cluster

I am seeing an error when trying to connect to Redis Sentinel Nodes from Spring boot app. It works fine when I connect directly to Redis Master Node from Spring Boot app without using sentinel nodes.

At App Startup I see the below in the logs,

```
2018-07-18 17:16:52.985  INFO [redis-cache-service,,,] 7548 ---  [           main] redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool     Trying to find master from available Sentinels...
2018-07-18 17:16:53.095  INFO [redis-cache-service,,,] 7548 ---  [           main] redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool     Redis master running at 127.0.0.1:6379, starting Sentinel listeners...
2018-07-18 17:16:53.221  INFO [redis-cache-service,,,] 7548 ---  [           main] redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool     Created JedisPool to master at 127.0.0.1:6379
```

When I access a service endpoint to fetch from cache, I get the following exception:

```
   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.TraceFilter.doFilter(TraceFilter.java:166)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:336)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:204)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.getConnection(JedisConnectionFactory.java:348)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:129)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:92)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:79)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:194)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:157)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:172)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.get(RedisCache.java:133)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:71)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:534)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:500)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:386)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:324)
        at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        ... 65 common frames omitted
    Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:53)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.getResource(JedisSentinelPool.java:209)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisSentinelPool.getResource(JedisSentinelPool.java:17)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:194)
        ... 96 common frames omitted
    Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:207)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:93)
        at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1767)
        at redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:106)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:888)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:432)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:361)
        at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:49)
        ... 99 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:184)
        ... 106 common frames omitted
```

I have my application configuration entries as below,

### Boot Application Configuration

```
# Redis Cache Configuration
spring:
  redis:
    sentinel:
      master: redis-cluster
      nodes: sentinelhost1:16379,sentinelhost2:16380,sentinelhost3:16381
  password: foobared
  cache:
    type: redis #The Type of Cache
```

## Sentinel Configuration

```
port 16379
sentinel monitor redis-cluster 127.0.0.1 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds redis-cluster 5000
sentinel failover-timeout redis-cluster 10000
logfile /var/log/redis/sentinel_16379.log
sentinel auth-pass redis-cluster foobared
protected-mode no
```

Similarly, I have 2 more Sentinel configurations with ports (16380,16381) for 2 other Sentinel Processes which are monitoring the Redis Master and via them the Redis Slave nodes.

## Master Redis Configuration

```
port 6379
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-master.log
dbfilename master-dump.rdb
protected-mode no
requirepass foobared
```

## Slave Redis Configuration

```
port 6380
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-slave.log
masterauth foobared
slaveof 127.0.0.1 6379
dbfilename slave-dump.rdb
protected-mode no
```

Can someone help me in identifying if there is any configuration missing/incorrect for Master,Slave and Sentinel nodes , so that I can successfully connect to Redis Master nodes.

Comment: Could you share the code where the `JedisSentinelPool` in instantiated or is this done by Spring under the hood?

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 1.5.14.RELEASE and have the dependency artifacts , "spring-boot-starter-data-redis" and "spring-boot-starter-cache" in my pom.xml. I assume spring is creating the JedisSentinelPool under the hood.